# SQL Server generate self-signed SSL certs performance concern?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Read this [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131691.aspx) article and doesn't seem to say if it keeps using the same self-signed cert after one is automatically generated.

If SQL Server generates a new SSL cert upon every connection (anyone confirm this?) or every time someone logs in, then does this cause any noticeable performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

The self-signed certificate is NOT generated upon every connection/login. So no performance hit here.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I don't see where it says that in the article.  Can you quote it?

Comment: "If a trusted certificate is not installed, SQL Server will generate a self-signed certificate when the instance is started, and use the self-signed certificate to encrypt the credentials."